# Why does Django app through an error when run in a Docker container

Tags: mysql, django, docker

Am building a Django microfrontend App using in docker. When i run the dev server with

````
python manage.py runserver  
```, the app spins up at
````

http://127.0.0.1:8000/

```
but after configuration with Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, as 
**Dockerfile**
```

```
FROM python:3.9
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app

CMD python manage.py runserver 8.8.0.0:8000
```

```
**docker-compose.yml**
```

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  backend:
   build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
   ports:
    - 8000:8000
   volumes:
    - .:/app
   depends_on:
    - db 


  db:
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: admin
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    volumes:
      - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 33066:3306
```

docker-compose up

```
throughs the error;
```

Django version 3.1.3, using settings 'admin.settings'
backend_1  | Starting development server at http://8.8.0.0:8000/
backend_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
backend_1  | Error: That IP address can't be assigned to.
admin_backend_1 exited with code 1

```
what am I doing  wrong, thanks


tried to change the server port at
```

```
CMD python manage.py runserver 8.8.0.0:8000
```

```
to
```

```
CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

```
expecting to host using my host machine IP address, but all in vain
```

Comment: You can't make up an IP address for the listen address option to `manage.py runserver`.  In Docker it typically _must_ be `0.0.0.0`; not a host IP address, an arbitrary address on net 8, or `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: so what can I do, otherwise when i change the CMD python manage.py runserver 8.8.0.0:8000 to 0.0.0.0:8000.

docker-compose up still brings the same persistent error 
backend_1 | Error: That IP address can't be assigned to. 
admin_backend_1 exited with code 1